# Function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick, online shell

Tags: html, function, syntax

I recently started learning HTML and I'm trying to generate random images from an array (I currently only have 2 images). The error I'm getting is:

> Blockquote Uncaught ReferenceError: randomImg is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_tut_img:1)
>   onclick @ tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_tut_img:1

And my code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="scream" src="https://cdn.modernfarmer.com/wp-
content/uploads/2014/09/cowhero2.jpg" alt="cow1" width="1200" height="742">

<p>Canvas to fill:</p>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1300" height="800"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>




<p><button onclick="randomImg()">Generate an error</button></p>


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function randomImg() {
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); 
var imgName = cow[randomNumber]; 
console.log(imgName);
console.log("myCanvas was run")
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img =r document.getElementById("imageid").src= https: + "//" + 
imgur.com + "/" + imgName; 
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It should also be noted that i'm just w3schools html shell.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you by showing an example. I know random 40 should work fine here.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="640" height="640"></canvas>
    <script>
      function getRandomInt(max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
      }

      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();
      var imname = getRandomInt(40);   
      imageObj.onload = function() {

        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'https://jacknorthrup.com/junk/'+imname+'.jpg';  
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```